# How can I prevent the removal of quotation mark when using $* within a csh script

Tags: python, csh

I have a csh script, which is a wrapper to send a python script into a grid engine. This works find as long as I don't use argument which contain quotes.

The csh 'my.csh script looks like:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
<grid command> my_script.py $*
```

my_script.py looks like:

```
#!<path>/python3.6
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def setup_arg_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-argument',help='Just an example.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = setup_arg_parser()
    print (args)
```

When call the my.csh  as follows it works fine

```
%> my.csh -argument \"-anything -is -fine\"
```

but when I do the folling the quotes will be removed and the python argument parser reports an error.

```
%> my.csh -argument "-this -does_not -work"
```

Is there a way to prevent this without escaping the quotes ? What I need is a way provide the quotes to the next script, here it is a python script.

Comment: You have forgotten to include the Python script in your question

Comment: `csh` is the pits, are you really sure you can't avoid it? Try `#!/bin/sh` `<grid command> my_script.py "$@"`